# load_balanced_view not working properly

Tags: ipython-parallel

I have some code that used to work with ipyparallel using a load_balanced_view.  I used to be able to:

```
from ipyparallel import Client
rcAll = Client()
lbvAll = rcAll.load_balanced_view()
for anInpt in allInpt:
    lbvAll.apply(doAll, anInpt)
lbvAll.wait()
lbvAll.get_result()
```

and then
    lbvAll.results.values()
would be a list of the results

however, now lbvAll.apply() does not work for me

I can do
    result = lbvAll.map_sync(doAll, allInpt)
and result is returned as a list of results.

Using 2-4 cores/engines, there is not much improvement using 4 cores over 2 cores.

My feeling is that ipyparallel has changed but I am not sure and I do not seem to using it correctly.  Thanks in advance for any help.

I am using Python 3.4.5, IPython3 5.1.0 and ipyparallel 5.2.0 on linux